# Exact change GLAccount for BankEntryLine

Tags: accounting, exact-online, process-accounting

Currently we import our bank transactions. Through the REST API I read all these transactions and try to match them to our internal invoices.

If I find a match I need to change the GLAccountCode from for example 1000 to 2000 for this particular BankEntryLine. All I see on the BankEntryLine is that I can do a GET or POST but no PUT method.

Is there something wrong with my approach? Like do I have to create something else that reconciles this transaction or is there a different way of updating this transaction line?

Example BankEntryLine:

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
            "uri": "https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/000000/financialtransaction/BankEntryLines(guid'123000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')",
            "type": "Exact.Web.Api.Models.Financial.BankEntryLine"
        },
        "Document": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "DocumentNumber": 00000,
        "EntryID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "EntryNumber": 00000000,
        "ExchangeRate": 1,
        "GLAccount": "100000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "GLAccountCode": "1000",
        "ID": "123000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "LineNumber": 1,
        "OffsetID": "000000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "OurRef": null,
        "Project": null,
        "ProjectCode": null,
        "ProjectDescription": null,
        "Quantity": null,
        "VATCode": "4  "
    }
}
```

API documentation: https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResources.aspx?SourceAction=10

BankEntryLine: https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=FinancialTransactionBankEntryLines

Answer (score 1):

There is no PUT or DELETE available for this API. I don't directly see another way to update/delete those lines.
Only possible workaround is to make a general journal entry to balance the amount of that suspense GL account to the one you need/want. But that will give you more entries and more lines to match.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I’m currently also waiting for a response from Exact. If they offer a better solution I will post it here and otherwise will try your solution. UPDATE: I just see that you work for exact. It’s strange there isn’t a better way because from the dashboard you’re able to change the GLAccount.